# Spritesheet: additional parameter

Tags: json, easeljs, preloader, sprite-sheet

I have a spritesheet in json file. I would like to add one more custom parameter for my needs to it, so it would look like that:

```
{
"images": ["ssheet.png"],
"frames": [
    [0, 0, 256, 192],
    [0, 194, 256, 192],
    [258, 0, 256, 192],
    [258, 194, 256, 192]],
"framerate": "24",
"dscaled": "0.4"
}
```

How do I access dscaled? It's undefined..

I thought I will get it there:

```
var ss = queue.getResult(spriteName);
var ds = ss.dscaled;
```

EDIT:

Here is how it's preloaded in PreloadJS:

```
{"id":"ss", "src":"images/ss.json", "type":"spritesheet"},
```

So if I preload it as a json (instead of a spritesheet) I will probably get my custom parameter available. But then I will need to preload PNG file separately and construct the spritesheet manually. Right?

Comment: Maybe you still access the cached copy of that JSON that didn't yet have a `dscaled` attribute?

Comment: If its just JSON loaded by PreloadJS, then it should be there. If you are looking for the property on a SpriteSheet instance, it will not exist, since the SpriteSheet data that is passed in is not preserved.

Comment: Sorry, there is currently no way to retrieve the JSON loaded by the SpriteSheetLoader. It's definitely a good idea, and I have [logged an issue](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/151) on the PreloadJS GitHub.

Comment: Quick update after some testing: You CAN access the raw JSON (text), which is stored as the `rawResult`: `queue.getResult(spriteName, true)`. We are making a recommendation to provide the formatted JSON as the raw result of a SpriteSheetLoader. https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work as it was suggested by Lanny:

Loaded it as a JSON file by preloader (not as a Spritesheet). That solved my problem as I was able to access my additional parameters. You just have to preload all linked images to the manifest as in that case it wouldn't do it for you.

Thanks!